# I am unable to add objects to my database as I am not able to initialize the Dao object in my background thread . even db.PetsDao() isn't helping

Tags: java, android, android-room

When I run the code I get that petsDao is a null object reference and if I try db.PetsDao() to initialize ,it isn't helping . I am new to android please help me out.

```
@Database(entities = {Pets.class},version = 1)
public abstract class PetsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static PetsDatabase instance;

public abstract PetsDao petsDao();

public static synchronized PetsDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                PetsDatabase.class,"Pets_Database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }

    return instance;
}

//This method is to insert dummy data in the database when the database is first created
public static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull @NotNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            private PetsDao petsDao;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                petsDao.insert(new Pets("Tommy","Terrier","Male"));
                petsDao.insert(new Pets("Snoopy","Unknown","Male"));
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When onCreate is called, the database has just been created and the Room build is incomplete (not fully instantiated) so you cannot use the Dao's.

You need to use **[`SupportSQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase)** methods. Such as **[`insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.content.ContentValues))** so you would have something like:-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("pet_name_column","Tommy");
cv.put("pet_breed_column","Terrier");
cv.put("pet_gender","Male");
db.insert("pets",SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE,cv);
cv.clear();
.... and so on
```

- Note that column names, such as **pet_name_column**, are only indicative of the column name being required and that the name is probably. Likewise the table name **pets** (first argument for the insert) is only indicative.

Comment: My Question Limit hase reached Can You help me with this     @Query("DELETE FROM EnquiryNoteEntity WHERE enquiryNoteId NOT IN (:enquiryNoteIds) ")
    suspend fun syncDeletedEnquiryNotes(enquiryNoteIds: IntArray)  This Query delete All the rows but i want to delete only those which id is not available in array list